# Why NHibernate simple select in HQL to SQLite database is not working?

Tags: nhibernate, sqlite, hql

I've recently started using FluenNHibernate and some weird problem appeared when I tried to write unit test with SQLite.

I use SQLite in memory database for test, for each test method I am clearing data existing in database. In example:

```
var u = new User() { Name = "Piotr" };
_session.Save(u);
_session.Clear();
var list = _session.CreateCriteria<User>().List();
```

This code works fine but when I write in the next line:

```
var list2 = _session.CreateQuery("FROM User").List();
```

I get:

```
System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: SQLite error
no such table: users
```

The sql query genereated by NHibernate is fine, so what can be the problem ?

Comment: You can try to flush the session before get your list again.

Comment: Sorry didn't see the error. May be, you confuse the database table name User and the name give in the mapping. You have to use the name from the mapping and not the table name

Comment: Is the second query really the next line in the code?

Comment: Are you sure your second query is not on another session?

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned that you're using an in-memory SQLite database.  NHibernate might be deciding to close the database connection in between the two statements, which would cause you to lose all of your tables.

One way of preventing this is to create a custom IConnectionProvider implementation that allows you to explicitly control when the connection is closed.

Here's what I used to handle this in a project:

```
public class InMemoryConnectionProvider : IConnectionProvider
{
    private static readonly object syncObject = new object();
    private static SQLiteConnection connection;

    #region IConnectionProvider Members

    public void Configure(IDictionary<string, string> settings)
    {
    }

    public void CloseConnection(IDbConnection conn)
    {
    }

    public IDbConnection GetConnection()
    {
        CreateConnection();
        if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            connection.Open();
        }
        return connection;
    }

    public IDriver Driver
    {
        get { return new SQLite20Driver(); }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }

    #endregion

    public static void CreateConnection()
    {
        lock (syncObject)
        {
            if (connection == null)
            {
                var builder = new SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder
                                {
                                    DataSource = ":memory:",
                                    BinaryGUID = true,
                                    DateTimeFormat = SQLiteDateFormats.ISO8601
                                };
                connection = new SQLiteConnection(builder.ConnectionString);
                connection.Open();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void DestroyConnection()
    {
        lock (syncObject)
        {
            if (connection != null)
            {
                connection.Dispose();
                connection = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You'd also need to set the `connection.provider` option in your config file to point to this class.

In your tests, you'd call the static `InMemoryConnectionProvider.CreateConnection()` method either at the beginning of the test or in a setup method.  When you're done, you'd call `InMemoryConnectionProvider.DestroyConnection()` to close the connection.  Since the implementation of `IConnectionProvider.CloseConnection()` is a no-op, NHibernate won't be able to close the connection on its own.

Comment: So to clarify, if I'm starting and disposing ISessions willy-nilly, then the database will definitely _not_ exist across ISessions?

If so, it would explain why, when I try to push a schema to an in-memory database before any ISessions are created, I get either "no such table" or, if I specify a schema in the *.hbm.xml files, "unknown database".

Comment: That's probably the case for the "no such table" error.

The "unknown database" sounds like something else, though. SQLite doesn't support schemas, but I think current versions of NHibernate fake it by using an underscore instead of a dot (i.e., "schema_table" instead of "schema.table").

If you're using an older version, or if you don't have the SQLite dialect configured, it might be trying to use the dot anyway, which SQLite interprets as trying to access another database attached via an ATTACH DATABASE statement (which I assume you haven't done).

Answer (score 0):

Name pluralizaion maybe? User - users.

Answer (score 0):

I've had issues with SQLite using the in-memory database.  The database is destroyed when the connection/session is closed.  Using the file variant seems to work better.

Also, the database entities have to be created as part of the session factory setup.  Try something like in the session factory setup:

```
        // Create schema.
        new SchemaExport(config).Create(false, true);
```